# Connecting to the Galaxybase graph database via Driver prompts "The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure"

Tags: graph-databases

I just ran into this problem when connecting to Galaxybase via Driver at the very beginning and this problem never came up before. It shows: The client is unauthorited due to authentication failure. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the username and password used for the connection is correct, or if the user is available in the current graph service.

If the above mentioned are confirmed to be correct, please contact customer service at the official website to check whether the license needs to be renewed.